# Pattern extraction

Tags: encryption

I got a DB (152.4 million users) (My own fake one).I did not hash the passwords, but encrypted them. So anyone that uses the same password, lets say, "123456", will have the same encryption/cipherkey. So what I need to do is extract the 100 most common cipherkeys.

Keys: http://shrib.com/uPB5ALVn

I did gap string db.txt

How do I turn all my extracted cipherkeys and replace the cipherkeys for plaintext?
I also need to extract the emails associated with the cipherkeys.

Comment: I'm not sure that this question is suited for this forum. This is not a security question, but a simple programming/scripting one.